# Cannot delete user profile in window 2003 server R2

Tags: windows-server-2003, user-profile

When I delete old user profile from Documents & Settings in windows server 2003 R2 (Terminal Server) I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot delete NTUSER:It is being use by another person.
```

I have already restarted my server but issue remains same. The profile is older more than 3 years and profile not to be used by any person but showing the above message. what is the issue. Please help me to sort out this problem.

Thanks

Comment: You should manually kill all processes by that user using taskkill.exe .

Comment: Try renaming the file or directory first, then deleting it?  Past that try running chkdsk?  Perhaps you have some filesystem corruption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try two things:

1. Make sure Symantec Backup Exec doesn't try to back up the folder/file, if it does, stop doing it and delete it after

---or---

If the ntuser.dat belongs to a user who has been deleted, then try to remove it by the following steps.

1. Log on using the Admin user.
2. Go to My Computer
3. right click and go to Properties.
4. Click Advanced Tab.
5. In User Profiles click Settings
6. Select Account Unknown and then click on Delete.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

you can use [handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655) by sysinternals to get the process name locking this file:

```
handle path/to/file/ntuser
```

then just kill that process.